# Wix Patch Bundle Servicing

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

Below is the source code for two very basic burn bootstrappers.   Bootstrapper installs 2 MSI packages and then SP1 performs a major upgrade on the appdata MSI package.  Initially this works very well except that I have several servicing probems.

1. When I remove the parent bootstrapper, it is smart enough to remove the child SP1 patch.  However, when I remove the SP1 update from Add/Remove programs, there isn't any appdata installed at all.  I have to perform a repair on the original Bootstrapper bundle to get the original version of appdata reinstalled.   Is this a bug or have I implemented it wrong?
2. I am able to install the SP1 bundle by itself.  How can I prevent SP1 from being installed if Bootstrapper isn't already installed?
3. If I create a Bootstrapper 2.0 it supersedes Bootstrapper 1.0 and SP1 correctly.  If I run Bootstrapper 1.0 it correctly blocks.  But if I run SP1 it installs.  How can I constrain SP1 to Bootsrapper v1 only?
4. If the first two items aren't currently possible, is it possible to create an SP1 that is not removable? ( Force removal and reinstallation of parent bundle to get back to the original state. ) I see how to use the DisableRemove and DisableModify attributes but then it doesn't show up in Add/Remove Programs at all and the user can still go back to the EXE and use the WiXStdBA to remove the bundle.

   ```
   <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
       <Bundle Manufacturer="ISWIX" Name="Bootstrapper" UpgradeCode="44a1059e-e7f7-46c7-9627-b720d6417d69" Version="1.0.0.0">
           <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
           <Chain>
               <MsiPackage SourceFile="app-1.0.msi"/>
               <MsiPackage SourceFile="appdata-1.0.msi"/>
           </Chain>
       </Bundle>
   </Wix>

   <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
       <Bundle Manufacturer="ISWIX" Name="SP1" ParentName="Bootstrapper" UpgradeCode="44a1059e-e7f7-46c7-9627-b720d6417d69" Version="1.0.0.1">
           <RelatedBundle Action="Patch" Id="44a1059e-e7f7-46c7-9627-b720d6417d69"/>
           <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
           <Chain>
               <MsiPackage SourceFile="appdata-1.1.msi"/>
           </Chain>
       </Bundle>
   </Wix>
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I posted XML but it wouldn't render.  This is the best I could come up with to share.

Comment: why dont you use the code sample {} to paste the actual XML.

Comment: I tried over and over. When I pasted just the XML it wouldn't show it all.  When I put it in a quote block or code block it rendered all weird.

Comment: Check this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052950/wix-burn-uninstallation

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: regarding the formatting, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item - in your case, I'd go with add-a-comment, as the code block isn't semantically part of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stopping your SP1 from being installed without the original bootstrapper you can make use of one of the following options:

Option 1: Make use of the bundle/@Condition attribute

```
<Bundle
    Name="Test123" Version="1.0.0.0"
    Manufacturer="abc cORP" UpgradeCode=""
    Condition="((VersionNT = v6.0)">
</Bundle>
```

This will only work with prebuilt wix burn variables. Detailed list of variables can be found here:[LINK](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)

Option 2: The second method makes use of the [WIXBALExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/) Condition element:

```
<bal:Condition
   Message="The Bootstrapper has to be installed in version $(var.BaselineVersion)">  
      WixBundleInstalled OR      
      ((SampleMsiInstalledState = 5) AND (SampleMsiInstalledVersion &gt;= v$(var.BaselineVersion)))
</bal:Condition>
<util:ProductSearch Guid="[msi_prerequisite_package_product_code]"
    Result="version" Variable="SampleMsiInstalledVersion" />
<util:ProductSearch Guid="[msi_prerequisite_package_product_code]"
    Result="state" Variable="SampleMsiInstalledState" />
```

Here we use a ProductSearch from the WixUtilExtension to find the state and versions of related msi packages. The version is then compared to the minimum version of a bundle that's required for the bundle (BasellineVersion).

[Related Link 1](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Some-in-burn-wixstba-similar-to-msiexec-x-ProductCode-td7581309.html#a7582139)
[Related Link 2](http://howdididothatthingagain.blogspot.com/2013/06/conditioning-wix-bundle-when-it-should.html)