# How to set UpgradeCode for burn Bundle

Tags: wix, burn

How should I select my UpgradeCode if I switch from a regular msi installer to a WiX burn bundle installer, in order to make the upgrade path from msi to bundle possible?

Example:

Version 1.0 was released as a normal msi installer with UpgradeCode=X

Version 2.0 will be released as a Burn bundle including the product and prerequisites such as .NET.  Which of the following alternatives should I use if I want the v2 bundle to be able to upgrade the v1 msi

A)  The msi inside should keep the UpgradeCode=X, and the bundle should use the same UpgradeCode as the msi it wraps. The v2 installer can upgrade the v1 install.

B) The msi inside should keep the UpgradeCode=X, and the bundle should get a new UpgradeCode=Y.

C) The msi inside should get a new UpgradeCode=Y and the bundle should take over UpgradeCode=X, so the bundle v2 can upgrade the msi v1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It should be option B, your MSI should have the same upgradecode as the original MSI which you released. The WIX bundle upgradecode has nothing to do with your MSI upgrade code.

**The  WIX bundle handles upgrades BOTH at the bundle level and also at the internal MSI level.**

So when you go from v1.o wix bundle to v2.0, it will upgrade the MSI within as long as the MSI itself has the same upgrade code as the previous one.

CHeck this question which is similar but not the same scenario. [WIX Burn Uninstallation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052950/wix-burn-uninstallation)